# Checking And Verify Purchase

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, verification

I made an app and released it onto the App Store costing $2.99 AUD.
I now want to make it free and block some features for a premium upgrade(In App Purchase) My problem is that I want the users who have already purchased the paid version get an update to the premium version of the free app.

I was wondering if there is a way to verify the user has purchased the in app purchase before on launch of the app and if it comes back saying they have purchased, they get the extra features and if not, they don;t

Is there any way to check or verify purchases??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to to check the original application version from the receipt. There is a [receipt field](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html) called `original_application_version`. This is the version of the app that was originally purchased. You can check the receipt to see if the original version is from when it was a paid download, and flag that this user is "premium".

Whether you want to do this locally or server side is up to you.

Note that download receipts are not present in Sandbox, but should be in production. So you'll have a receipt even if no in-app purchases have been made. If for some reason there isn't a receipt present on the device, you should have a restore purchases button that will return a receipt where you can check the original application version.

Comment: And How would I implement this into it so it runs and checks on the viewDidLoad() and maybe I use a switch and cases for if before or after certain date they got version? What would the code look like @enc_life

Comment: It should probably live wherever you do a check for the existing "premium" status, and it sort of depends on how you do that. You could just require all grandfathered users to do a "Restore Purchases" and do the check on that receipt you get back.

Comment: Would I get the same effect buy just running a restore purchases function on the view did load so the people who update and already bought will seemlessly get the premium version or do it this other way with original application version? @enc_life

Comment: Just calling restore purchases in itself doesn't unlock any functionality, you still need to parse the receipt and either check for an active subscription or original application version. There should be a receipt file already on the device you can check at launch for the original application version. Presumably you're checking if someone is "premium" on app launch, and you could incorporate this receipt check there as well. Save the result somewhere though so you don't have to parse a receipt every time the app launches (slow).